# Inner tube size.

Tags: tire

What inner tube can I use for a 700x26c tire? It has a Schrader valve. At the stores I went to I found a 700x25c tube & a 700x28c tube. Which tube would be best since I can't find a 700x26c tube?

Comment: Most tubes will list a *range* of sizes.  Eg, 700x23 through 700x28 (and also, for the same tube, 27" x  0.9 through 27" x 1.1).  If not, any tube of the same diameter and within about 3mm of the same width is OK.

Answer (score 3):

Most inner tubes do not cover an exactly specific size such as 25c or 28c or anything like that. Any tube I've ever used has had something of a variety of tyre sizes which they can mold too.

For instance, with the size you're looking for, you would most likely find tubes rated to fit size 23c-28c, possibly even something like 25c-30c. I myself have 28c tyres and my inner tubes are ranged from 28c-35c.

So depending on the type of tyre/tube combination you are using, I don't see why you would have a problem finding something that will work for you.

Below is an example picture of what you should see on the tube/packaging.

[image]